# Linux C socket - keep server alive

Tags: c, linux

I'm using C to implement a simple client-server retrieval system with Linux socket. I've now successfully connect the remote server, but when I close the connection, the server went down, i.e. the server program stopped.
What should I do avoid this?

here's sample of my code:

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void)
{
   int optval;
   socklen_t optlen = sizeof(optval);

   char str[100] = "";
   int listen_fd, conn_fd;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

   listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   // check if on
   getsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, &optlen);
   printf("keep alive is %s\n", (optval? "ON" : "OFF"));

   // set it on
   optval = 1;
   optlen = sizeof(optval);
   setsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen);
   printf("done, check again.\n");

   printf("keep alive is %s\n", (optval? "ON" : "OFF"));

   bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   // set appropriate protocol and port number (15792)
   // the htons() function converts the unsigned short integer
   // from host byte order to network byte order.
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port = htons(15792);

   // Bind a name to a socket
   bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   // listening for incoming connection
   listen(listen_fd, 10);

   // accept a connection on a socket
   conn_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

   do
   {

      // set str to null
      bzero(str, 100);


      // Read from a file descriptor (linux all)
      read(conn_fd,str,100);

      // print the received message
      // printf("Received: %s\n",str);

      if (!strcmp(str, "GET TIME\n"))
      {
         bzero(str, 100);

         time_t clocks;
         clocks = time(NULL);
         sprintf(str, "%s", ctime(&clocks));
         write(conn_fd, str, strlen(str));
         //close(conn_fd);
      }
      else
      {
         bzero(str, 100);
         strcpy(str, "ERROR: No such command.\n");
         write(conn_fd, str, strlen(str));
         //close(conn_fd);
      }
   } while (1);
}
```

client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   // declare necessary variables
   int sockfd;
   char recv[1024] = "";
   char command[100] = "";
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

   if (argc != 2)
   {
      printf("usage: %s <ip address>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


      // create a socket with the appropriate protocol
      if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
      {
         printf("ERROR: Failed create cosket.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // Set all the socket structures with null values.
      bzero(&servaddr, sizeof servaddr);

      // set appropriate protocol and port number (1999)
      // The htons() function converts the unsigned short integer 
      // hostshort from host byte order to network byte order.
      servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      servaddr.sin_port = htons(15792);

      // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
      if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(servaddr.sin_addr)) <= 0)
      {
         printf("ERROR: Wrong ip address.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      // attempt to connect to a socket
      if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
      {
         printf("ERROR: Failed at connect.\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("------ connect successfull ------\n");
      }

   do
   {

      printf("> ");
      fgets(command, 100, stdin);
      write(sockfd, command, strlen(command));

      if (!strcmp(command, "QUIT\n"))
      {
         close(sockfd);
         break;
      }

      // print the receive stuff
      read(sockfd, recv, sizeof(recv));
      fputs(recv, stdout);
      bzero(recv, 1024);

   } while (1);
}
```

Comment: Well depending on *how* your server went down, you should either catch or ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal, or you should use a debugger to find any run-time errors (crashes).

Comment: i am not sure why, but i can't see your code. your question ends with: "here's sample of my code:"

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg it just ended with no error

Comment: @linluk Maybe you could see now

Comment: yes, now i can see it

Comment: To start with you really need to check for errors when you use those system calls. You have no idea if e.g. `read` fails with an error, or even if the connection is closed. To continue you really need to handle connection errors or even just a nicely closed connection, which you do not do now (well you *can't* since you don't check for it). And to reiterate my first comment, you need to handle (one way or the other) the `SIGPIPE` signal.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks for ur advice, but my question here is, why server ended if I close the connection from the client.

Comment: Because then the blocking `read` call will return the value `0` indicating the connection was closed, which you promptly ignore. You then try (and fail) to compare the received data (which you have none) to the string and you will attempt to write the error message to the (now disconnected) client which will raise the `SIGPIPE` error which terminates your application.

Comment: First I doubt your Server is terminating, it has a do-while(1) Loop without an Exit Point (you do not check for socket Errors and then Exit the loop). Second the Server will not allow any more incoming Connections because you do do not accept() again. Third you do not properly Close the sockets you create.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thank you so much! I've solved my problem now, and i'm be able to improve it.

Comment: Plus all the usual suspects. Cargo-cult 'bzero(recv, 1024);',  missing/inadequate handling of returns from system calls, no-NULL-termination UB if the read completely fills the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In your server code, the `accept()` function must be called in the do-while loop:

```
// listening for incoming connection
listen(listen_fd, 10);

do
{ 
    // accept a connection on a socket
    conn_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

    ...

    close(conn_fd);
} while(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> my question here is, why server ended if I close the connection from
>   the client.

Because then the blocking `read` call will return the value `0` indicating the connection was closed, which you promptly ignore. You then try (and fail) to compare the received data (which you have none) to the string and you will attempt to write the error message to the (now disconnected) client which will raise the `SIGPIPE` error which terminates your application.
                    – Some programmer dude